# Kubuntu 12.04 Won't let me search for wireless network

Tags: wireless, kubuntu

Hello I'm running a brand new Kubuntu 12.04 single boot on my laptop, this is the first time I tried connecting to a wireless network.

I tried using the network manager app allready on the task bar, but it doesn't let me tick the column to search for wireless networks, i.e. it will untick it automaticaly, it's dissabled by the software or the hardware, but I doubt it.

I've tried searching the other questions on this site, and I can't see anything which helps with my problem.

I know my wireless card is a `Atheros AR9285`, I don't think I installed any firmware for it, I'm sorry I can't offer more info but I'm completely new to networking and all that I have for the network to connect to are it's name and password of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to unlock it by typing int the terminal `sudo rfkill unblock wlan0`.

Comment: It says wlan0, which the app confirms is the name for my wireless card, is a bogus argumment for unblock.